# How to customize default Login Form of Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I have created the login Form with the following code:

```java
    private LoginForm loginForms() {
        FlexLayout o = new FlexLayout();
        LoginForm component = new LoginForm();
        return component;
    }
```

This gives the following form:

[image]

Now, I want to change the title of the form to something else from `Log in`.

Move `Forget password` to the right and add `Stay Signed in` with checkbox in front of it.

Is it possible to do so ? If yes, how can I do that ?

**Note: I am using Vaadin 14**

Answer (score 5):

For the text, take a look at [some of the official examples](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples). In short, you have to create an internationalization (i18n) object

```
LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();
```

then change the properties you want, e.g. to change the title and error message

```
i18n.getForm().setTitle("Custom title");
i18n.getErrorMessage().setTitle("Invalid credentials");
```

then you just apply it to the `LoginForm`

```
myLoginForm.setI18n(i18n);
```

---

As for your second question, it can not currently be configured in that way. There are issues in the issue tracker that suggests adding these features, go and leave a thumbs up if you have a GitHub account.

[Add "remember me" checkbox](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login/issues/87)

[Make LoginOverlay more configurable](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login/issues/96)